# Replace one value with another on each line

Tags: regex, string, sed

Given the following sample lines of text (extracted from a much large file):

```
<document id='3316200' srcDocId='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61A9A0fmN7L.jpg'</document>
<document id='3306829' srcDocId='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71sQDUoJbmL.jpg'</document>
<document id='2406251' srcDocId='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71j7ISxAOdL.jpg'</document>
<document id='2534144' srcDocId='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71VXMXcrg2L.jpg'</document>
<document id='3417415' srcDocId='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ymoo32gVL.jpg'</document>
```

How would you programmatically replace the `srcDocId` value with the `id` value on each line?

I have completed this task using a combination of regex and **sed** but I think there is a simpler solution and that's what I am asking.  I did the following:

1. Replace srcDocId with id using regex:

Regex: `(id='.*?') (srcDocId='.*?')`

Regex substitution: `$1 $1`

An example of this regex can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/fS2qT0/1

2. Take regex replacement output and run **sed** to replace second occurrence of `id=` with `srcDocId=`:

Sed: `sed 's/id=/srcDocId=/2' input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap the values by using the following regex substitution:

```
id='(.*?)' srcDocId='(.*?)'
```

With `id='$2' srcDocId='$1'` as replacement.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ6zU8/1)

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.  Works perfectly.  I marked this as the correct answer because it was the simplest.

Comment: Just in case there are really unknown number of spaces between the two attributes, you may use `id='(.*?)'( +)srcDocId='(.*?)'`,  or `id='(.*?)'([[:blank:]]+)srcDocId='(.*?)'` and the replacement will be `id='$3'$2srcDocId='$1'`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a non-greedy quantifier in sed.

```
sed "s/id='\([^']*\)'[[:blank:]]\+srcDocId='[^']*'/id='\1' srcDocId='\1'/g" file
```

If you want to swap then try this,

```
sed "s/id='\([^']*\)' srcDocId='\([^']*\)'/id='\2' srcDocId='\1'/g" file
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I did try it and it works perfectly.  If you had been the only answer I would mark this as correct but since you can only have one answer marked correct you'll have to settle for an upvote :)

Comment: @Stuart did you try the other answer in sed?